# Multiplying a float and int in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point

Iam a beginner to php. When i tried to multiply a integer value with a decimal ,get the results as follows.

1.00 * 5 = 0 .
I want the output as 5.00
How is can be done using php?

Comment: Are you sure one of those values isn't a string?  Even with strange integer casting rules, you should at least get the value `5`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you're looking for [`number_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
number_format(1.00 * 5, 2); // "5.00"
```

See it here in action: http://codepad.viper-7.com/mSFpqH